# Gradient descent's cost function: Mean Squared Error vs. Sum of Squared Errors

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

In many introductory Machine Learning textbooks or online resources, the cost function to be optimized with gradient descent to find a linear regression model is the Mean Squared Error (MSE), defined as: $$MSE=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i (x_i -\hat{x}_i)^2$$
(often multiplied by 1/2 for derivation convenience). But why use MSE instead of Sum of Squared Errors (SSE, aka Residual Sum of Squares or SSR), namely $$SSE=\sum_i (x_i -\hat{x}_i)^2$$ and get stuck with the 1/n factor?

Comment: I mean $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_i (x_i -\hat{x}_i)^2$$ is minimal if and only if $$\sum_i (x_i -\hat{x}_i)^2$$ is, so they are equivalent

Comment: Yes, yes, of course. But since they are equivalent, why make it "complicated" by using MSE?

Comment: This is just a way to normalize the number of your data points, otherwise you can prefer one model of the other because it has less data points. In any case it's meaningless if you use the same dataset, and for linear regression we're more interested in the *argmin*, not the actual minimum value. This does not change due to scaling (as you mentioned, it's customary to multiply by $\frac{1}{2}$ so the derivative is "nicer").